# How can we truncate text after space in Hadoop?

Tags: sql, string, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column say `column_1` and its values are:

```
abc 12edf
hbnm 847
47sf hg41
```

I need the output as follows:

```
abc
hbnm
47sf
```

PS: I have read only access to the db

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp_extract(col,'^(.*?)\\s',1)` to extract everything from the beginning of the string before space (group 1) in the regexp.

`'^(.*?)\\s'` means:

`^`- the beginning of the string anchor
`(.*?)` - any character any number of times
`\\s` - space

```
Demo:
with your_table as (--use your_table instead of this
select stack (3,
'abc  12edf',
'hbnm 847',
'47sf hg41'
) as str
)

select regexp_extract (str,'^(.*?)\\s',1) as result_str 
  from your_table s
```

Result:

```
abc
hbnm
47sf
```

One more possible solution is using `split`:

```
select split (str,' ')[0] as result_str
```

And one more solution using `instr`+ `substr`:

```
select substr(str,1,instr(str,' ')-1)
```